# Determining cloud cover from observer to near the horizon

Tags: weather

Does there exist a [Clear Sky Chart](http://cleardarksky.com/c/SanFranCAkey.html?1) with the following enhancements?:

1 - Actual Cloud Cover (Offered Visually and not just Colors with a Legend, Over Time/Past & Predictive)

2 - Simulate/Predict Cloud Cover taking into account the direction from Observer to Observed Object and [Angle of view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view) - Close to the horizon (May be helpful to know when you can reasonably start/end tracking something you want to catch that night that is close to the horizon)

The reason I'm curious is:

A) I wonder if it's just not feasible for any/many reasons.

B) It would be great help to know this information.

In general, does anyone know of other Earth Weather, Clear Sky Clocks and Charts or anything else that gives more information?...anything related will be helpful.

EDIT: I would love to find this lecture "You can do better than Clear Sky Chart" mentioned: http://stjornuskodun.blog.is/blog/stjornuskodun/entry/966941/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rain Today](http://www.raintoday.co.uk/) provide a rain cloud image down to 15 minutes prior.  But rain cloud doesn't always equate to total cloud cover.

I think the major drawback is that clouds can arise from clear air as the moisture condenses, and predicting where this is going to happen becomes too complicated to resolve at fine enough detail to be of much use...

Comment: More explicitly, weather prediction is deep black magic in the supercomputer field, so anybody hardcore enough to actually attempt it is going to be responsible for a large area ala the National Weather Service (or major news outlets doing their own regional weather? I don't know if they actually do that or not.), not the one pinpoint of sky directly above a particular observatory.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you are not aware of the enormous amount of work which has been put into the Clear Sky Charts we have by two extremely generous and knowledgeable gentlemen: Alan Rahill of Environment Canada, who teased their supercomputer into generating the weather maps, and Attilla Danko, who persuaded Alan's maps to generate customized charts for hundreds of individual sites. Perhaps if you would write to them expressing your wishes *politely*, they might be able to accommodate you.

Comment: I'm more curious as to the technical limitations as apposed to getting something for myself. I have used Clear Sky Charts and at many sites for years and do appreciate their amazing work.